# Copy cells and paste contents into a text box

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, copy, paste

I have 2 worksheets - 'Venn Diagram Helper' consisting of a series of named ranges of data - and 'Venn Diagram' with a number of text boxes over a Venn Diagram image.

I have a drop-down list on the Venn Diagram worksheet in cell C5 which I wish to use to trigger the copying and pasting of specific ranges into specific text boxes.

I would like the user to select from the drop down list - the options are 'End of Phase 1', 'End of Phase 2' or 'End of Year' and for the names of the individuals in the appropriate named range to be copied and pasted into the text box with a ';' separating each name.

I have started to write the code but, as I am a novice at VBA and I have been trying to adapt examples I have found online, it doesn't work. Can any of you spare the time to help me out with the 'reading' text box please? I am confident that, once I have the model code, I will be able to adapt it to fill the remaining text boxes.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then

Dim Helper As Worksheet
Dim Venn As Worksheet
Dim EoP1Rdg As Range
Dim EoP2Rdg As Range
Dim EoYRdg As Range
Dim Rdg_TxtBox As OLEObject

Set Helper = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RWM Venn Diagram Helper")
Set Venn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RWM Venn Diagram")
Set Rdg_TxtBox = Venn.OLEObjects("Rdg_TxtBox")

With Helper
    Set EoP1Rdg = .Range("AQ4:AQ103")
    Set EoP2Rdg = .Range("AX4:AX103")
    Set EoYRdg = .Range("BE4:BE103")
End With

If Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) = "End of Phase 1" Then
        With Helper
            .Select ("EoP1Rdg")
            .Copy
        End With

        With Venn
            .Select Rdg_TxtBox
            .Paste
        End With
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: 25/9 5pm

I have changed the data validated drop down list to a combobox as advised below. I have rewritten the code but it still does not work correctly (no text is copied into the textbox). Can anyone advise me further please?

```
Sub DropDown5_Change()

Dim Helper As Worksheet
Dim Venn As Worksheet
Dim EoP1Rdg As Range

Set Helper = Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram Helper")
Set Venn = Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram")
Set EoP1Rdg = Range("EoP1Rdg")

If DropDown5 = "End of Phase 1" Then

Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram Helper").Select
    Range("AQ4:AQ103").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 7")).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Name 15" & Chr(13) & "Name 16"

End If

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail please? What 'doesn't work' exactly? Is there an error (if so what?)? What output does it give vs. what you're aiming for?

Comment: It doesn't do anything if I change the selection in the drop down list. I have just tried to adapt the code further and have put the macro it in the code for the sheet rather than as a module in the workbook but nothing happens. I have edited the code to reflect what I now have tried.

Comment: I could be/am probably completely wrong with my approach and code so any advice would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using the in-cell drop down list from the Data Tab->Data Validation.  You've selected a Worksheet event, which gets fired every time you click on a cell or make a selection of a group of cells (a range).  The event will not fire when selecting a value in the Data Validation drop down.

You want to go to the Developer Tab, and click on Insert button, and insert a Combobox.  See the picture below:

[image: Developer Button Bar]

The ComboBox is the second button in the first row under the Forms Control section.  You'll want to avoid the Active X Controls, until you become more proficient with VBA.

You should review Microsoft's [Overview of forms, Form controls, and ActiveX controls on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2).

Once you drag, drop, and resize the ComboBox, you can click on "View Code" found on the button bar to the right of "Insert".  This will open up the VBE code editor, and this is where you'd want to write the code that handles the change event.

I don't have your workbook, so I can't show you everything that might need to be changed.

In the code below, I've attempted to show the difference between Recording a macro and programming in VBA.  The big change is the statement just before the `End If` where you assign the text string to the Shape.

```
If DropDown5 = "End of Phase 1" Then

    'This piece of code shows you clicking on the RWM Venn Diagram Helper sheet
    'Which if you're writing the code, you need to do the following
    'Declare and set an object variable to the Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    'Declare and set an object variable to the Helper worksheet
    'in this case source (srcWS)
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = wb.Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram Helper")

    'Declare and set an object variable to the Digram worksheet
    'in this case target (tarWS)
    Dim tarWS As Worksheet
    Set tarWS = wb.Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram")

    'Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram Helper").Select
    srcWS.Activate

    Range("AQ4:AQ103").Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Sheets("RWM Venn Diagram").Select
    tarWS.Activate

    'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 7")).Select
    tarWS.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 7")).Select

    'This statement is used by the macro generator to clear the
    'clip board when you complete the paste operation
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'I haven't seen any paste function at this point.

    'Change this to the statement that follows
    'Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Name 15" & Chr(13) & "Name 16"
    'This assumes that the Venn Diagram is on target sheet
    'That it is shape 1 - if there's only one shape, probably
    tarWS.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Name 15" & Chr(13) & "Name 16"

End If
```

Comment: Hi Jamie - thank you for the pointers. You guessed correctly. I'll go back to the sheet and try what you have said. Thanks again.

Comment: So I have made the changes and tried to rework the code but it does not work as nothing gets pasted into the text box. I used the Macro recorder to perform the actions I want to perform when the 'End of Phase 1' option is selected but, while it works as a standalone macro, it does not work in the DropDown5_Change() macro.

Comment: I will edit the original post to include the new code. If anyone can provide some advice pointers, or rework it for me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I like your effort and at this point I highly recommend you get a book on VBA programming.  It'll teach you more and provide lots examples.  While we can help you solve a lot of problems, we can't teach you everything you're going to need to know to accomplish this project.  I use [O'Reilly's Safari Books Online](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/home) to get access to great technical books.  They offer various subscription models -- or you can buy a book from Amazon.  I like the book "Programming Excel with VBA", it's more advanced than the entry level  books.

Comment: Thank you for the reworking and the detailed explanations - these have been really useful. I'll keep plugging away at the other aspects! Thanks for the advice re the books, too. I will definitely look them up.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used any code that pastes on textbox, but I have used code to run when a cell with data validation is changed.
Your script was correct, how ever to my (very limited knowledge) you have to add the intersect part directly on the worksheet where you have the data validation. and have it call a sub in a separate module. At least that has worked for me in the past.

It could be something like this:

(on the worksheet)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then
    Call DropDown5_Change
    End If

End Sub
```

(on a module)

```
Sub DropDown5_Change()

Dim Helper As Worksheet
Dim Venn As Worksheet
Dim EoP1Rdg As Range
Dim EoP2Rdg As Range
Dim EoYRdg As Range
Dim Rdg_TxtBox As OLEObject

Set Helper = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RWM Venn Diagram Helper")
Set Venn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RWM Venn Diagram")
Set Rdg_TxtBox = Venn.OLEObjects("Rdg_TxtBox")

With Helper
    Set EoP1Rdg = .Range("AQ4:AQ103")
    Set EoP2Rdg = .Range("AX4:AX103")
    Set EoYRdg = .Range("BE4:BE103")
End With

If Range("C5") = "End of Phase 1" Then
        With Helper
            .Select ("EoP1Rdg")
            .Copy
        End With

        With Venn
            .Select Rdg_TxtBox
            .Paste
        End With
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps